# Unable to fetch all records using Where condition on primary key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a primary key on `item_no`column.
But when i run `select * from table` it gives me 2 records and when i do a select on the primary_key it gives me only 1 record.
Please help me what could be the cause

[image: Select statements]

[image: Design of table]

[image: ltrim rtrim]

Comment: Include len(item_no)

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have a trailing space or other non-printable character at the end of one of your `item_no` values.

Try `select * from [db4].[dbo].[test] where rtrim(ltrim(item_no)) = '1234'`

And for the love of all that you hold dear, **stop storing numbers as strings**. That will eliminate this problem entirely. While you're at it, make that `date` column a `date` data type (with a more descriptive name) as well because I can almost guarantee you that by storing it as a string, you're going to end up with invalid data at some point. It'll also store, index, sort and process (someday you'll have to do a date range on your search, I'm sure) more efficiently.

**Edit:** Based on your update, you have a *different* whitespace character - tab, newline, etc. in there. You have to `REPLACE()` them all until you get to the right one.

Or try `cast`ing your value to an integer. `select * from [db4].[dbo].[test] where cast(item_no as int) = '1234'`

But either way, by doing this you've killed the performance of the query and the correct solution is to store your numbers as numbers or failing that, sanitize your input or put a constraint on the table to prevent invalid characters from being written.

Comment: Yes the value has trailing space at the end.But i have tried using rtim,ltrim but ended up with same output. I'm updating the question with another image. @alroc

Comment: @joeprince see my edit

Comment: My bad, but forgot to mention that actual item_no has characters too in the value so its a mix of Numeric and Character @alroc

Comment: @joeprince then the field is poorly named and you *still* have to deal with `REPLACE()`ing any non-alphanumerics either in the query or when you insert the data. Either way, this is a poor design and IMHO you need to start over.

Comment: I agree the field name is poorly named. Also i have tried using replace() but still it gives me one record.@alroc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the goal is here, but if you are trying to eliminate the second record with the non-printable character and retain only the correct record you may be able to identify it using `LIKE` and `<>`

```
SELECT *
    FROM [db4].[dbo].[test]
    where item_no LIKE '1234%'
    AND   item_no <> '1234'
```

but this will only track the ones that begin with 1234. You could add a leading '%' but that might return additional rows.